# weird PDO query result

Tags: php, pdo

Well, the weakest point of PDO is inability to debug it because prepared statements are actually stored on a server side. I spent the whole day around the problem that I cannot understand at all. So, here is the case:

```
//the query itself
            //Did other customers from the list buy the same style in last 3 months?
            $end = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $start = strtotime("-3 month", strtotime($end));
            $start = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $start);
            $q = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) as totals FROM web_order
                            JOIN web_order_item ON web_order_item.od_id = web_order.od_id
                            WHERE web_order.p_vendor IN (:id)
                            AND od_pcode = :pcode
                            AND od_date BETWEEN :start AND :end
                            ');
            $q->bindValue(":pcode", '1008GD');
            $q->bindValue(":id", $custList);
            $q->bindValue(":start", $start);
            $q->bindValue(":end", $end);
            $q->execute();
            echo "SELECT COUNT(*) as totals FROM web_order
                            JOIN web_order_item ON web_order_item.od_id = web_order.od_id
                            WHERE web_order.p_vendor IN ($custList)
                            AND od_pcode = '1008GD'
                            AND od_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'";
            $res = $q->fetchAll();
die(print_r($res));
```

And here comes the funny bit - `print_r($res)` prints the empty array.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [totals] => 0 [0] => 0 ) )
```

While echo statement with exactly the same query prints

> `SELECT COUNT(*) as totals FROM web_order JOIN web_order_item ON web_order_item.od_id = web_order.od_id WHERE web_order.p_vendor IN ('210','1107','2295','2452') AND od_pcode = '1008GD' AND od_date BETWEEN '2012-06-13 00:00:00' AND '2012-09-13 13:15:36'`

If I execute the echoed query by itself I get 'totals' column to have a value of 1. At the same moment PDO statement returns nothing.

Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Although the answer was posted, I still do not get why this did not work. $custList is actually a string, not an array, because I used

```
$custList = implode(",", $custList);
```

Comment: By the way I heard from someone that it is possible to set up PDO to store prepared statements locally for debugging purposes. Has anyone heard of it?

Comment: Your problem is at IN(:id) ... take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition for approaches to this problem

Comment: Value binding is not the same as variable interpolation or copy and paste. `:id` means a placeholder for exactly *one* value, not a number of values.

Comment: But deceze, I used the implode function so there is only one string I bind

Comment: Yes, so you are binding the value `'210','1107','2295','2452'`, literally. You are not binding the four separate values `'210'`, `'1107'`, `'2295'` and `'2452'`, you are binding the *one* value `'210','1107','2295','2452'`. Unless you have a field that contains literally "'210','1107','2295','2452'" in your database, it won't match anything.

Comment: Okay, seems I got it. I'll try to find any info regarding value binding and how it works internally

Comment: It doesn't really matter how it works internally, it's enough if you understand it on a conceptual level. It does not matter what the contents of the bound values are, it's all understood to be one value. A comma in the bound value does not separate the next value, a quote does not close the string. You are entirely separating the *syntax* from the *content*. Maybe see [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ken mentioned in the comments on your question, your problem is the `:id` binding, namely, that PDO doesn't allow you to bind an array as a param. You'll need to loop through the array and bind the individual elements into the query.

Generally, I handle this with a `foreach` loop that adds a `?` to the query for each element of the array, then I bind each of the elements into the query in the correct order with the other prepared variables (since `?` is positional, instead of named).

Comment: Yes, this works now, thank you. Although this makes the code less readable and overall this does not look good. I used the implode function so basically I am not binding an array, but I am binding a string. Why did not it work?

Answer (score 0):

What I see is two big errors :
first is explained by @Joe but the second is here :

```
$q->bindValue(":start", $start);
$q->bindValue(":end", $end);
```

You forgot to say "those parameters are integers so do not quote them" by passing a third argument.
    $q->bindValue(":start", $start,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $q->bindValue(":end", $end,PDO::PARAM_INT);

Comment: These are actually not integers but strings representing dates

Comment: Ok... something weird in my brain, I checked three times before posting my answer that you put :start and :end in LIMIT close, but I was wrong. 
I think the "implode" solution is the best. If you want readability, wrap the implode inside a function called "toMysqlSet" that takes an array and output a string formate as you want in your query.